# Mongodb does not releasing connections?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have implemented an application using spring, while investigating mongodb logs i see that connections only increasing not releasing in a week

```
  Tue Jul 23 11:26:04 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:38772 #92 (83 connections now open)
Tue Jul 23 11:27:59 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:38789 #93 (84 connections now open)
Tue Jul 23 11:28:44 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:38794 #94 (85 connections now open)
Tue Jul 23 11:29:08 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:38802 #95 (86 connections now open)
Wed Jul 24 05:46:09 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:39045 #96 (87 connections now open)
Wed Jul 24 05:46:32 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:39048 #97 (88 connections now open)
Wed Jul 24 05:47:14 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:39054 #98 (89 connections now open)
Wed Jul 24 05:48:44 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:39057 #99 (90 connections now open)
Wed Jul 24 11:41:50 [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:39146 #100 (91 connections now open)
```

I do not want mongodb to reach maxConnection limit and stuck one day, how could i handle this situation ?

mongodb version:2.2

Best Regards

Thank you

Comment: MongoClient maintains internal connection pool. You can configure maximum number of connections. Have a look also at my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810527/mongodb-open-connection-issue/17811055#17811055

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [MongoDB connection reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/) and the maxIdleTimeMs option if you want to close idle connections.

That being said, reaching the maximum number of connections doesn't mean the application will get stuck, it just limits the number of connections the application can use concurrently.

Comment: `maxIdleTimeMs` property is not implemented for all drivers. Specifically for Java, I can see that it is still unresolved https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-710

Comment: Fair enough, though in @ytech's case, releasing connections isn't going to help anything get more or less "stuck" anyway.