# Issue on opening MongoDB Connections after calling close Method

Tags: java, web-services, mongodb, session, enums

I am working on a web project using java with mongoDB as back-end database.To open a connection once and reusing the same for each service contained in the project, i am following the below URL
[mongodb open connection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810527/mongodb-open-connection-issue) .For closing the connections which are opened, i'm using the function `MongoDBClass.INSTANCE.close();` during the user logout of the session in web site.But the problem is, once the user login the session again it produces the following error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: state should be: open`.That means the connection is not opened , `MongoDBClass INSTANCE` is not reinitialized so `MongoClient` is not reopening the connection.But after the server restarts login works perfectly for first time. How to build a new connection again after when i call close method during logout the session of user without restarting the server. I am using the following code

```
public enum MongoDBClass {
    INSTANCE;

    private static final String MONGO_DB_HOST = "hostURL";
    private Mongo mongoObject;
    private DB someDB;
    String DB_NAME = null;
    MongoClientOptions options = null;

    MongoDBClass() {

        options = MongoClientOptions.builder().connectionsPerHost(100)
                .readPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred()).build();

        mongoObject = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(MONGO_DB_HOST, 27001),
                options);
        someDB = mongoObject.getDB(Nutans_Mongo.getNameOFDB());}}

    public DB getSomeDB() {
        return someDB;
    }

    public void setSomeDB(String dbName) {
        someDB = mongoObject.getDB(dbName);
        DB_NAME = dbName;
    }    

    public String close() {
        mongoObject.close();
        return "true";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MongoClient` maintains a connection pool internally so there is no need to open/close a client for each request.  Also, Java enums are not meant to be used this way.  Any state an enum has should be globally usable as there will only be one instance of a enum value per ClassLoader/VM.  When you call `close()`, you're globally closing that enum's `MongoClient`.  Since you open the connection in the constructor it never gets reopened because a another `INSTANCE` is never created.

There are several approaches to ensuring a singleton-like lifecycle of objects in a servlet context.  Using CDI to create and inject a `MongoClient` in to your servlet is one way.  Using a `ServletContextListener` and static field is another, if slightly less savory, approach.

Comment: I used ServletContextListener to open and close once when the server starts and stopped.Like  @Override
 public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent contextEvent) {
  mongodb.INSTANCE.close();
 }

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I'm using the Mongo Java driver 3.0.0.
I upgraded my database from 2.4 to 2.6. But the problem persists.
When I don't close the connection, next time it connects successfully, but in this case open connections raises quickly.

Comment: Open and close the connection when server starts and stops.By using ServletContextListener i have fixed it.In my case when apache tomcat server starts the connection to mongo db will open.when i stops the tomcat it will close the connection